# Win 10 home networking - Unable to cut, copy, or paste a folder or text file into the "root" of the "shared" folder

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, network-shares

I'm unable to cut, copy, or paste a folder or text file into the "root" of the "shared" folder, from desktop to laptop, at home over Wi-Fi.

Although, I can cut, copy, and paste into "sub-folders" of the "shared" folder on the laptop. This works as expected.

I can also make a "New" folder in the "root" of the "shared" folder on the laptop, and then cut, copy and paste folders or text files into it.

I can also cut and paste a text file from the "root" of the laptop, onto the desktop.

What's going on?

It looks like the folder is "shared", but it's set up so you just can't cut, copy, or paste anything new into the "root" directory.

The fix appears to be:  If I put everything in a sub-folder of the "shared" folder, and then work from that, it works as expected.

But my question is: Why can't you cut, copy, and paste into the "root" of the "shared" folder?  It supposed to be "shared".

Comment: What sort of server is it that you are trying to paste the file to? Need much more infomation to help

Comment: No server, it's just me at home using . . . HP z240 PC Workstation desktop . . . HP 840 G3 laptop . . . Win 10 Pro on both . . . over WiFi . . . I backup from the laptop to desktop by making a mirror image with SyncBack Pro . . . It seems like this is just the way it works, but it is not "as expected" to me, so I just want to ask and verify.

Comment: So to clarify, you are trying to move files from your laptop to the z240 and this doesn't allow you. Have you tried adding your laptop as a trusted host on the z240? This can be done in powershell quickly. Assuming the "share" you speak of is a folder on the z240 c drive, you should be able to access this via admin share. e.g \\z240machinename\c$ in the run menu should get you in. Either way, i think if you add the laptop as a trusted host on the z240 it may fix.

Comment: I have not looked into how to use PowerShell, but I almost have it,
so it seems like I should be able to accomplish this without PowerShell.

I initially did this section on just the Laptop - you got me to thinking:

Maybe it should be done on the Desktop also - I found that this was off, but "on" doesn't help:
. . . Public folder sharing / [dot] Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in Public folders

Comment: I can still only cut and paste from Laptop to the Root of Desktop.
I still cannot cut and paste from Desktop to the Root of Laptop.

Cut and paste between a sub-directory ("7") works as expected, though.

Comment: I would put in the full story here, but they make you keep everything short.

Comment: I see this question is here also:

Windows 10 1903/1909 can't copy files to shared folder root . . . https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/651fe7aa-6e34-4b30-968c-789386b9039f/windows-10-19031909-cant-copy-files-to-shared-folder-root?forum=win10itprogeneral

I'm using 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1706)

Xyplorer took 30 seconds to open, and then, the laptop on the Network was nowhere to be found - there was nothing under Networks

My conclusion: Just use File Explorer, and work from a sub-directory on the Root.  File transfer is fast over WiFi, and works as expected, both ways.

Answer (score 0):

One more step on top of you creating a sub-folder and putting everything inside. Instead, I created a sub-folder, name it whatever you want. Make it hidden because most users don't have show hidden files on by choice or policy. Inside of that make a shortcut to the root. **But**, another hiccup, when I right click and create a shortcut, the user had a permission error. I had to create the shortcut by right clicking the root and sending it to desktop. You can see the difference in the file type column. One made by right clicking and creating a new shortcut says shortcut but a send to desktop shortcut says file folder.

Example:
\\Server1\Share$ - We can't paste into a shortcut that has this path.

Solution:
\\Server1\Share$\fix\Share - *fix* would be the new folder you create. An actual folder, not a shortcut. Make it hidden if you want. *Share* at the end will be the 'shortcut' you create by right clicking the root and sending to desktop or any comparable way that you know how to create a file folder file type shortcut instead of just shortcut file type. Take that shortcut you sent to the desktop and put it inside of *fix*.
When inside of the fix folder, if you start typing share in the address bar it will pop up with the name of the shortcut that you used, finish typing it exactly, don't hit enter or anything, copy and paste that line from the address bar to use as your shortcut path on the user end.

Depending if you're on the server or another machine with full permissions to that location, you may need to adjust the path. If it says \\Server\E$\Share\fix\share, you may need to remove E$ or use \\Share$\fix\share depending on how your system is set up. The path that gave a permission error was \\Server1\Share\fix\Share.lnk if that is what you're using, don't.

Comment: I just took another look at it, and it's working as expected. The only things I've had to change since is the IPv4 Address now and then, from powering the modem off and on now and then to fix connection problems.  I have read that drivers can affect WiFi also.  It works fine how I've been doing it though.

Comment: It happened again, except this time, a text file would not copy - I use SyncBackPro to make a Mirror copy of a folder on my Laptop to the Desktop.

If I created a new text file in the Shared Folder, it would backup, so, I determined it must be some issue with properties of the text file.

Comment: I compared the two, and saw that the one that did not copy, was not Shared. At this time, I don't know how I got a text file with properties like that, into the Shared folder.  As far as I know, I actually created that text file, on the laptop, within the Shared folder, so, no idea what's going on.

I got it to work, by just toggling the Shared folder settings off and on, then it saw it.